# Keeping state on none form element by adding a class

Tags: knockout.js

Hi I have a situation where I have a hidden field and an ul with 10 items when the user clicks on one of the li's the input get's updated and class is added to the current li.Here is the code:

```
    <ul>
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 1 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">1</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 2 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">2</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 3 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">3</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 4 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">4</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 5 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">5</a></li>
         <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 6 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">6</a></li>
         <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 7 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">7</a></li>
         <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 8 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">8</a></li>
         <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 9 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">9</a></li>
         <li data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade == 10 }"><a data-bind="click: $root.updateHiddenField">10</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $data.grade"/>

   function updateHiddenField(model, event) {
        var link = $(event.currentTarget);
        link.parent().parent().find("li").removeClass("active");
        link.parent().addClass("active");
        var value = link.text();
        model.grade(value);
    }
```

This is how the app looks:

[image]

When the user clicks on one of the buttons the value of the hidden field is update but I am using jQuery to add the class.

The problem appears when I click on the button on the left and go to a different category , and then come back here.When I do this the hidden fields have the correct value but the li's do not persist the active class , and they looked like they have never been pressed.In reality the value is saved in the binded observable but the user has no way of knowing that.

As it can be seen I have tryed to add a conditional class using this statement :

```
**css: { active: $data.grade == 1 }**
```

But it did not seem to work.

All the data including the categories are one single model.

Can anyone assist me with this problem?

Comment: Your css binding should look like this : `data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade() == '1' }"` note the `()` after grade and the `''` around 1.

Comment: thanks that was the reason pls write the it as an anwer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `grade` is a `ko.observable` therefore you need to get its value with `grade()`.

So you need change your `css` bindings to:

```
data-bind="css: { active: $data.grade() == 1 }"
```

And you can greatly simplify your `updateHiddenField` method

```
function updateHiddenField(model, event) {
    var link = $(event.currentTarget);       
    model.grade(link.text());
}
```